# "Nonlinear cosine" integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $\alpha > 1$, $\xi \in\mathbb{R}$.
 and $\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of the set $A$.

Are there some known ways of computing (or estimating in terms of $\xi$) of this kind of integrals?
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(\xi x)\cos( (1-x)^{\alpha} ) \chi_{[0,1]}(x) dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts we obtain
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(x\,\xi)\cos((1-x)^{\alpha})\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\,dx=\frac{\sin\xi}{\xi}-\frac{\alpha}{\xi}\int_0^1\sin(x\,\xi)\sin((1-x)^{\alpha})(1-x)^{\alpha-1}\,dx.
$$
Since $\alpha-1>0$, the last integral converges to $0$ as $\xi\to\infty$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(x\,\xi)\cos((1-x)^{\alpha})\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\,dx=\frac{\sin\xi}{\xi}+O(\xi^{-1}),\quad\xi\to\infty.
$$
Depending on the value of $\alpha$, the integration by parts can be done more times, obtaining better asymptotics.